# How to create Property for below JSON value in c#?

Tags: c#, json, properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUNtc.png)How to create Property for below JSON value in c#?

```
{
"charts":[
"CaseStatusChart",
"InvoiceStatusChart",
"QuoteStatusChart"
],
"recent_activities":[
"Accounts",
"Cases",
"Calls"
],
"counters":[
"Cases",
"Calls",
"Accounts",
"Documents"
]
}
```

Comment: I have literally no idea what you asking

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately you haven't really given us enough information about what you're trying to do, or what you've already tried. It looks like you should probably declare a class with a `Charts` property, a `RecentActivities` property and a `Counters` property, for example.

Comment: I think he want to create class file base on JSON string. @Hardik

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I want to add properties for above JSON data.

public Dictionary<string, List<RootObject>> Luck { get; set; }

Answer (score 2):

Either format using online tool like [json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) or if you are using visual studio then follow the below steps:

1. Copy the JSON Open a file
2. List item
3. Go to Edit - Paste specials -> **Paste JSON as classes**.

[image]

The class for JSON will be

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> charts { get; set; }
    public List<string> recent_activities { get; set; }
    public List<string> counters { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Details 
{
    public string[] charts { get; set; }
    public string[] recent_activities { get; set; }
    public string[] counters { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will benefit people very new to programming if you can add an explanation to it (apart from the code snippet)